# Merging columns based on the percentage column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has numerical and categorical values. Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is to merge the data based on a specific criteria. The criteria is when merging rows, once the percentage column becomes 100%, merge those rows into one. The numerical rows will be averaged and the categorical values will be listed.

I am here for ideas on how to tackle the problem in the most efficient way possible in python preferably.

Here is what the dataframe looks like:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th><th>a</th><th>%</th></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>8</td><td>lem</td><td>or</td><td>0.5</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>9</td><td>lem</td><td>or</td><td>0.5</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>10</td><td>lem</td><td>or</td><td>0.3</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>9</td><td>or</td><td>or</td><td>0.7</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>8</td><td>or</td><td>or</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is what the final dataframe would look like:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>z</th><th>a</th><th>%</th></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>8.5</td><td>lem, lem</td><td>or, or </td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>9.5</td><td>lem, or</td><td>or, or</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>8</td><td>or</td><td>or</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, let's try:

```
s = df['%'].cumsum()
grp = s.where(s.mod(1).eq(0)).bfill()
df.groupby(grp, as_index=False).agg({'x':'mean', 
                                     'y':'mean', 
                                     'z': ", ".join,
                                     'a':", ".join, 
                                     '%':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
    x    y         z       a    %
0   5  8.5  lem, lem  or, or  1.0
1   5  9.5   lem, or  or, or  1.0
2  10  8.0        or      or  1.0
```

Comment: Now the next step is to make it more dynamic so we do not have to keep updating the dictionary in the agg(). Thanks for your answer!